# I am trying to combine w3schools responsive page with image effects cant see conflict

Tags: css, position, responsive

my goal is to have a responsive page 3 by 3 of images and apply the opacity effect with a button. Combining the w3 tutorials. I have two issues.

First the effect works on the last four images. If I hover over the first image it changes the second image. When I hover over the second image the button is too high. The rest are fine. The first image is also showing some margin or padding on it too.

Second issue is the responsive part is not working. I am thinking relative but I don't understand relative.

I renamed the classes in case there was a conflict in w3css. Here is my code. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<style>
.containerImage {
position: relative;
width: 30%;
}

.imageMid {
opacity: 1;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
transition: .5s ease;
backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.midButton {
transition: .5s ease;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 80%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.containerImage:hover .imageMid {
opacity: 0.3;
}

.containerImage:hover .midButton {
opacity: 1;
}

.text {
background-color: #000000;
color: white;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-row-padding">

<div class="w3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="w3-row-padding">

<div class="3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="3-third containerImage">
<a href="www.s3schools.com">
<img src="Collars.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="imageMid" style="width:100%">
<div class="midButton">
<div class="text">SHOP NOW</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very critical issue. OMG !!!!!
Typo Error : You missed "W" in class name.
Your Code : `<div class="3-third containerImage">`
Correct Code : `<div class="w3-third containerImage">`
I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: If I could give you ten Green Check marks I would!!! Thank you so much. That was it. Find and replace got to double check your replace. Again Thanks!